# Randomly choose between oh my posh themes from a list or file

Tags: powershell, power-automate

I have chosen a few themes and saves their names in a file but I don't want to randomly choose from all the themes, rather choose from my own list which is saved in a text file (not a csv, just a text file).

$Profile exists with values

```
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config "$env:POSH_THEMES_PATH\paradox.omp.json" | Invoke-Expression
Import-Module -Name Terminal-Icons
```

What to type in the profile to achieve this?
Or how can this task be automated in power automate?

I also want to do the same for command prompt (cmd).

values in my text file

```
catppuccin.omp.json
clean-detailed.omp.json
cloud-native-azure.omp.json
dracula.omp.json
hul10.omp.json
hunk.omp.json
if_tea.omp.json
jandedobbeleer.omp.json
M365Princess.omp.json
sonicboom_dark.omp.json
```

the file is located in `~/Documents/my themes.txt`

Comment: Solution for ```$Profile``` (ps1)

```ps1
Import-Module -Name Terminal-Icons
$random_theme = Get-Content "C:\Users\Jawad11\Documents\my themes.txt" | Get-Random
echo $random_theme.name
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config "$env:POSH_THEMES_PATH\$random_theme" | Invoke-Expression
```
Looking for other answers, for command prompt and wsl as well.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called `themes.txt` containing the names of the themes you'd like:

```
amro
wholespace
kushal
catppuccin_latte
# ... add more themes here
```

Add the following to your `Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1` file:

```
# Select a random Oh My Posh theme
$themes = Get-Content -Path "/path/to/themes.txt"
$selected_theme = $themes | Get-Random
$base_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/main/themes/"
$terminal_theme_url = "${base_url}${selected_theme}.omp.json"

# Set the random theme to an environment variable
Set-Item -Path Env:TERMINAL_THEME -Value $terminal_theme_url

# Print the theme name when your terminal session starts
echo "Oh My Posh Theme: $selected_theme"

oh-my-posh init pwsh --config $env:TERMINAL_THEME | Invoke-Expression
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete answer, but I can't format the comments so here goes the answer to powershell script.

```
Import-Module -Name Terminal-Icons
$random_theme = Get-Content "C:\Users\Jawad11\Documents\my themes.txt" | Get-Random
echo $random_theme.name
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config "$env:POSH_THEMES_PATH\$random_theme" | Invoke-Expression
```